# Array function on a logic-tested OFFSET

Tags: excel, row, array-formulas

I have a simple function in Excel.

In column A, I have some numbers. In column B, I have a function in the form (for B6): `{=MAX(ROW(A$1:A5)*(A$1:A5<A6))}`

This is all well and good. It finds the nearest preceding row with a value less than the current row's. But if I insert a row, one of the functions will get messed up, simply because there are relative references.

I have tried converting the `A$1:A5`'s to `OFFSET`s, but for some reason, that doesn't work:

`{=MAX(ROW(OFFSET(A$1,0,0,ROW()-1))*(OFFSET(A$1,0,0,ROW()-1)<A6))}`

Having broken it down with some testing, it's clearly the second instance of `OFFSET`, and the associated logical test, that is causing the problem. But I can't figure out why. Or how to fix it.

Is there a way of getting this to work, or an alternate way of performing this query that will be insert-safe?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `ROW` function is problematic because it returns an array even when you expect a single value, e.g. it returns {6} instead of 6.

Try forcing this array to a single value using a function like `MAX` or `SUM`. e.g.

`=MAX(ROW(OFFSET(A$1,0,0,ROW()-1))*(OFFSET(A$1,0,0,SUM(ROW())-1)<A6))`

Comment: Thanks for that. The SUM() stopped the error, which means that a returned array was likely the problem. However, for some reason, it failed to give the expected results. I'll have to play with it further.